# both jquery and mootools loaded but mootools adds css elements to div

Tags: jquery, mootools

I have both jQuery and MooTools loaded but mooTools adds more elements and I can figure out why. When I remove mootools it works perfectly. Unfortunately I need mootools for other unrelated scripts.

```
  beforeImg.addClass("halfhalf-before");
  afterImg.addClass("halfhalf-after");

  container.append("<div class='halfhalf-shandle'></div>");
  var halfslider = container.find(".halfhalf-shandle");

  // append additional html element
  var overlay = container.find(".halfhalf-overlay");
  overlay.append("<div class='halfhalf-before-label'></div>");
  overlay.append("<div class='halfhalf-after-label'></div>");

//adjustContainer
  var aContainer = function(offset) {
    beforeImg.css("clip", "rect(0,"+offset.cw+","+offset.h+",0)");
    container.css("height", offset.h);
    $('#debug5').html("offsetWidth: " + +offset.cw+","+offset.h+",0)");
  };


  var adjustSlider = function(pct) {
    var offset = calcOffset(pct);
    halfslider.css({left: offset.cw, top: '50%'}); //When I moved the slider top and absolute gets over written
    $('#debug6').html("left: " +offset.cw); // nothing changes in the debug.
    aContainer(offset);
  }
```

Comment: to prevent conflict between jquery and mootools use `jQuery.noConflict()' 
Refer: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: Its already there globally... where else do I use it?

Comment: What do  you mean with "mooTools adds more elements" ? do you mean DOM elements? do you mean CSS properties?classes?

Comment: It adds
  
element.style {
left: 813px;
top: 334px;
position: absolute;
}
but only supposed to have 
element.style {
left: 113px;

}

Comment: The code you posted above is mostly jQuery... can you make a __[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)__ or paste a live link so we can see the problem live?